# Filter Table dataset using like in socrata

Tags: c#, socrata, soda

I am trying to run a filter on the dataset which is private in Socrata. I have tried doing it through browser and using SoQL but it doesn't work.

https://xxxxx/resource/xxxx-xxxx.json?$where=product like '%test%'

When I am making request to the following URL in browser. It is returning me all the products without any filtering. But it occasionally throws an exception

```
{
  "code" : "query.compiler.malformed",
  "error" : true,
  "message" : "Error, could not parse SoQL query \"select * from #xxx-xxxx where product like '%new%'\"",
  "data" : {
    "query" : "select * from #tatp-bcb2 where product like '%new%'"
  }
}
```

It is private dataset so I am unable to access specific API docs from export menu.
Is it because the dataset is private or something to do with the actual API ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably what has happened is that you're using the latest API endpoints for your public datasets, which support `LIKE`, but for your private dataset, you're still using the older API endpoint, which will reject the use of `LIKE`.

If you have a Data Lens page for your private dataset, you can get its new API endpoint through that user interface under the `API` button. Or, if you email me at `chris.metcalf (at) socrata.com` I can look up the new API endpoint for your private dataset.

We're working on an authenticated way of getting API docs for private datasets, but its not ready yet.

Comment: I don't have direct access to the private data set. But it is only shared with me from the client that I am working for. I am unable to access the data lens page because I don't have access to dataset. I will send the email to you with dataset name. Is it still possible to use 'like' function without getting access to the actual dataset or I can ask client to create a dataset lens page for me ?